# How can I set path to load data from CSV file into PostgreSQL database in Docker container?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to load data from CSV file into PostgreSQL database in Docker.
I run:

```
docker exec -ti my project_db_1 psql -U postgres
```

Then I select my database:

```
\c myDatabase
```

Now I try to load data from `myfile.csv` which is in the main directory of the Django project into `backend_data` table:

```
\copy backend_data (t, sth1, sth2) FROM 'myfile.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

However I get error:

```
myfile.csv: No such file or directory
```

It seems to me that I tried every possible path and nothing works. Any ideas how can I solve it? This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Which container is `myfile.csv` in, `django` or `db`? Which container are you exec'ing into? `django` or `db`?

Comment: @Alasdair `myfile.csv ` is in main directory where is also `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` of Django project. I execute `\copy backend_data (t, sth1, sth2) FROM 'myfile.csv' CSV HEADER;` in `project_db_1 `.

Comment: you did not mount any volume for the `db` container, the file `myfile.csv` is not in the `db` container, and you are running the command in that container. Possible solution add in docker-compose.yml `volumes: - "<path_to_csv_in_local>:<path_to_csv_in_db_container>"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to mount a directory into the postgres container, place the file into the mounted directory, and reference it there.

We are actually mounting the `pgdata` directory, to be sure that the postgres data lives even if we recreate the postgres docker container. So, my example will also use `pgdata`:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - "<path_to_local_pgdata>:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
```

Place `myfile.csv` into `<path_to_local_pgdata>` (relative to directory containing the config or absolute path). The copy command then looks like this:

```
\copy backend_data (t, sth1, sth2) FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/myfile.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: And `local_pgdata ` has to be in main directory?

Comment: If it is a relative path, then `local_pgdata` has to be relative to the main directory, yes.

Comment: In `docker-compose.yml` should be `- "./local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"` Thank you for your help.

Comment: What if my CSV file is in another container, how can I place it into db volume path?

Answer (score 1):

you need to mount the path of the `myfile.csv` in the `db` container if you are running the command in that container.

you might have mounted the file only in `django` service.

possible `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - <path_to_csv_in_local>:<path_of_csv_in_db_container>
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

you haven't created a mount of your `db`. this will act fatal once you close your database container (you will lose all your data). `postgresql` container stores data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. you need to mount this this path to your local system to maintain the data even if the container closes.

```
volumes:
  - <path_of_db_in_local_system>:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: How can I check what is my `path_of_db_in_local_system`?

Comment: you can set it to anything you wish it to be (and accessible by docker service).. it will be the path where any data stored in your container (basically any model based operation that django application performs on postgres) will copy to the local system, so that you have your database intact even if the container closes due to unforeseen circumstances.

Comment: Okay, but so I should have two volumes - `<path_to_csv_in_local>:<path_of_csv_in_db_container>` and `<path_of_db_in_local_system>:/var/lib/postgresql/data` or it is the same?

Comment: not necessary if you are mounting data directory path (which should always  be mounted to avoid losing data) then simply copy that excel in that mounted directory path and it will be available in the container. Suppose you use `volumes: -/var/lib/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` then simple copy your csv file in `/var/lib/postgres/` and it will be available in `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata`.

Comment: `ERROR: for django  Cannot start service django: Mounts denied: 
The path /var/lib/postgres
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
`

Comment: check my second comment (also accessible by docker service). `/var/lib/...` paths are not accessible by docker in MacOSX (they are accessible in debian based systems), so you can simply use `volumes: -./pgdata/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` and copy your csv file in `./pgdata`. `./pgdata` will be accessible by docker.

Comment: Hmm my volumes looks in this way `volumes:
      - ./pgdata/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` After docker rebuilding pgdata was created automatically in main directory of project. Then I added `myfile.csv` to this pgdata directory and finally I ran `\copy backend_data (t, sth1, sth2) FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/myfile.csv' CSV HEADER;` but I got `No such file or directory`

Comment: @user7304253 Did you get any solution?