# Uploading csv file in docker using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have an unconventional question. I have established a db in Postgres

`psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 15432 -U postgres`

And created a table in the db using:

```
$ docker=# CREATE TABLE cities (
docker(#     name            varchar(80),
docker(#     location        point
docker(# );
```

However, I haven't been able to upload a csv into the table I've created. Can you please show me how to do it?
(I am using Docker Command window to do this)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your csv file located? can you access it from within the container?

Comment: my csv file is located on my desktop

Comment: so, I am assuming you can't access it from your container. If that's the case, you'll first have to add data volume or manually copy that file when you build the image. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849539/how-can-i-set-path-to-load-data-from-csv-file-into-postgresql-database-in-docker to get started

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample of copying lat/lon points in a CSV to the cities table using psql inside of a container.

```
# Sample CSV data
echo "somecity",45,-45 > cities.csv

# Create database
docker run --name postgres -p 15432:5432 -d postgres

# Create cities table and a temp table for loading point coordinates
# Uses host network to access database published on port 15432 of the host
docker run --rm --network=host postgres psql -h localhost -p 15432 -U postgres -c '
  CREATE TABLE temp (
    name varchar(80),
    latitude numeric(12,8),
    longitude numeric(12,8)
  );
  CREATE TABLE cities (
    name varchar(80),
    location point
  );'

# \copy data from file (mounted by volume)
docker run --rm --network=host -v `pwd`:/data postgres \
  psql -h localhost -p 15432 -U postgres -c \
    "\\copy temp FROM '/data/cities.csv' WITH csv"

# Insert into cities creating point from coordinates
docker run --rm --network=host postgres psql -h localhost -p 15432 -U postgres -c "
  INSERT INTO cities (name, location)
  SELECT name, point(temp.latitude,temp.longitude) 
  FROM temp;
  DROP TABLE temp"

# Show the point
docker run --rm --network=host postgres psql -h localhost -p 15432 -U postgres -c \
  "SELECT * FROM cities;"
```

The last command outputs:

```
  name   | location
----------+----------
 somecity | (45,-45)
(1 row)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm really new to this thing. I'm trying your method will get back to you asap

Comment: Hi, it is giving the following error  "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond." @logan rakai

Comment: The commands I gave run the database and client on the same machine so I could verify that it works locally. You may need to modify localhost to 192.168.99.100 as you wrote in your question.

Comment: sorry I'm getting bunch of errors when running the code to create a db I receive ":\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.33/containers/create?name=postgres: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running."

Comment: These errors appear to be related to your installation of Docker and not related to my answer or the initial question. I'd suggest checking your docker installation and posting a new question if necessary.

Comment: when I try to create table I receive syntax error at or near docker. Why would that be?